# How to work with characters encoding in a Django project?

Tags: python, django, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters

I'm working in a Django Project and I get a mess when I have to work with different encodings.

Is not there a way to work without having to worry about this?

I try to fix it by putting unicode(), but this does not always work... and I have to put it in all my functions. That's awful! :(

I do not have any experience about this and I'm just looking for some advice that can help me.

Normally the problems are with accents and the Spanish letter 'ñ'.

For example:

```
upload_main_file.name #DocumentÑ.pdf
with default_storage.open(new_path, 'wb+') as destination:
... 
...
```

Error:

```
<type 'tuple'>: ('ascii', u'dir1/dir2/DocumentoN\u0303.pdf', 76, 77, 'ordinal not in range(128)')
```

Thank you very much.

Python: 2.7
Django: 1.8

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow.com. Please take some time to read the [help pages](https://stackoverflow.com/help), especially the sections named ["What topics can I ask about here?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) and ["What types of questions should I avoid asking?"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). Also please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and read about [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) good questions. Lastly please learn how to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Comment: Can we assume you've read the official Python [Unicode HOWTO](https://docs.python.org/2/howto/unicode.html)? You should seriously consider learning Python 3. It has much saner Unicode handling, and Python 2 will reach its official End Of Life in 2020. In the mean time, you may find this article helpful: [Pragmatic Unicode](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html), which was written by SO veteran Ned Batchelder.